# A-frame .obj model geometry and events

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to set mouse events on obj. model in A-frame. I've noticed that my object won't trigger any mouse events (mouseenter, mouseleave, click...). So I've added `geometry="primitive: box; height: 50; width: 50; depth: 50"` to the object and the events started to work... But I want the object to trigger events not the box inside.

**Questions:**

Is there a way to make a complex geometry that resembles the object?
Am I doing something wrong and my object should trigger mouse events without geometry property?

**Code:**

```
<a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="heart-obj" src="Heart.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="heart-mtl" src="Heart.mtl"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>

<a-entity   id="heart"
    obj-model="obj: #heart-obj; mtl: #heart-mtl"
    geometry="primitive: box; height: 50; width: 50; depth: 50"
    scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" 
    position="0 1.6 -12" 
    event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; _target: #heartText; visible: true"
    event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; _target: #heartText; visible: false">
    <a-text id="heartText" 
        value="This is a heart" 
        align="center" 
        color="#FFF" 
        visible="false"
        scale="10 10 10"
        position="-15 24 27"
        geometry="primitive: plane; width: 2" 
        material="color: #333">
    </a-text>
</a-entity>

<a-camera>
    <a-cursor id="cursor"></a-cursor>
</a-camera>
```

**Imports**

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@3.0.3/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's likely that you're running into the bug discussed here: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2980

Comment: Adding an invisible box wrapping around the object (not inside) isn't a terrible workaround in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip @DonMcCurdy.

So I've added ([from](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3067)):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('raycaster-refresh', {
  init: function () {
    var sceneEl = this.el.sceneEl;
    sceneEl.addEventListener('object3dset', function () {
      var raycasterEl = sceneEl.querySelector('[raycaster]');
      raycasterEl.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();
    });
  }
});

<a-scene raycaster-refresh>
...
</a-scene>
```

Mouse events work even without the box inside the 3D object now.